# Weird output from Android TextView

Tags: java, android, process, output, bufferedreader

I am trying to run a ping command from my android app and to see the output in a TextView , but the result is some gobbledygook.

This is my output:

```
java.io.BufferedReader@4144f2d0
```

And this is my code:

```
try {

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 5 192.168.1.2");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txtview.setText("output:\n"+in); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to set the text as for a "BufferedReader" which will invoke the toString() method and gives you the current output.

Comment: What you have to do is use the BufferedReader object and read data from it and display that.

Answer (score 3):

you need to read a `string` from `BufferedReader`

```
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = in .readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
    }
   txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
   txtview.setText("output:\n"+total.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The "weird" output you are getting is the object code of `in`. You might want to use `in.read()` in the `setText()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thats what you will get, you are trying print the `bufferedreader` try `bufferedreader.readline()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`txtView.setText("output:\n"+org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(total);`